# Flutter dio http headers don't attach from interceptor

Tags: flutter, dart, interceptor, dio

I have a Dio client with an interceptor attached, but when I try to add some headers, they don't appear in logs.
his is my code

```
 Dio dio(KeyStore keyStore) {
    final Dio dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
      contentType: 'application/json',
      connectTimeout: 5000,
      sendTimeout: 5000,
    ));
    final Dio tokenDio = Dio();
    tokenDio.interceptors.add(LogInterceptor(responseBody: true));

    dio.interceptors.add(LogInterceptor(responseBody: true));
    dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(onRequest: (options, handler) async {
      final accessToken = await keyStore.readAccessToken();
      final branchId = keyStore.readBranchId();

      dio.lock();
      options.headers[HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader] = 'Bearer: $accessToken';
      options.headers['x-tenant'] = branchId;
      handler.next(options);
      dio.unlock();
    }));
    return dio;
  }
```

Request headers...

```
I/flutter ( 8872): *** Request ***
I/flutter ( 8872): uri: https://api.someapi.com/users/058c026a-2dce-47e7-9fe1-61dec507265f
I/flutter ( 8872): method: GET
I/flutter ( 8872): responseType: ResponseType.json
I/flutter ( 8872): followRedirects: true
I/flutter ( 8872): connectTimeout: 5000
I/flutter ( 8872): sendTimeout: 5000
I/flutter ( 8872): receiveTimeout: 0
I/flutter ( 8872): receiveDataWhenStatusError: true
I/flutter ( 8872): extra: {}
I/flutter ( 8872): headers:
I/flutter ( 8872):
```

Answer (score 3):

Dio interceptors are run in order.  Since your auth interceptor is added after the log interceptor, `LogInterceptor` is called first, before the auth interceptor has a chance to add headers.  The interceptor code looks fine to me, so I suspect that the authorization headers are correctly sent to the remote server.

To make your logs reflect the headers added by the auth interceptor, make sure `LogInterceptor` is the last element of the list `dio.interceptors`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to use an interceptor.
You can update the default options like this:

```
dio.options.headers = {
  HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer: $accessToken',
  'x-tenant': branchId
}
```

Then subsequent requests will use these values by default.